# Compile an enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What do `enum`s become at runtime in TypeScript?

*Fruit.ts*

```
enum Fruit {APPLE, ORANGE};
```

*main.ts*

```
var bowl = [Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.ORANGE];
console.log(bowl);
```

The generated `main.js` file just stays the same as the `.ts`, however that won't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The JS for that code will be:

```
// Fruit.js
var Fruit;
(function (Fruit) {
    Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 0] = "APPLE";
    Fruit[Fruit["ORANGE"] = 1] = "ORANGE";
})(Fruit || (Fruit = {}));

// main.js
var bowl = [Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.ORANGE];
console.log(bowl);
```

You're probably looking for a `const enum` though:

```
const enum Fruit {APPLE, ORANGE};
```

If you use that, then the values of the enum will be inlined to the JavaScript:

```
// Fruit.js: empty.. nothing will be in here

// main.js
var bowl = [0 /* APPLE */, 1 /* ORANGE */];
console.log(bowl);
```

You can use a `const enum` when the JS code that a regular enum generates isn't necessary in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Fruit` outside of fruit.ts then you will need to export it...

```
export enum Fruit {APPLE, ORANGE};
```

And in another file when you want to use it, you will need to reference it...

```
import {Fruit} from './fruit';
var bowl = [Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.ORANGE];
// btw, love the name "bowl" here
```

Also, in order to use `import` you will need to specify a module type in tsconfig.json (or via cmd line argument)

Comment: Hm, is it `tsconfig.json` or will `.tsconfig` also work? Does `grunt-ts` take this file into account (I have already set a module output format in `Gruntfile.js`)?