# Why does TypeScript use object property assignments as object keys and variable assignments as function arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, compilation

In the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872363/10415695) for a question titled [*"Compile an enum in TypeScript"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32871129/10415695), the following TypeScript:

```
enum Fruit {APPLE, ORANGE};
```

Is shown to compile to this JavaScript:

```
var Fruit;
(function (Fruit) {
  Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 0] = "APPLE";
  Fruit[Fruit["ORANGE"] = 1] = "ORANGE";
})(Fruit || (Fruit = {}));
```

On `line 3` and `line 4` an object property assignment is being used as an object key:

```
Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 0] = "APPLE";
Fruit[Fruit["ORANGE"] = 1] = "ORANGE";
```

And on `line 5` a variable assignment is being used as a function argument:

```
})(Fruit || (Fruit = {}));
```

From what I understand, the `Fruit = {}` is wrapped in parenthesis so it isn't a named argument.

Instead it's evaluated and passed to the IIFE as it's first argument but only if the first `Fruit` is `undefined`, which it is probably is (`line 1`: `var Fruit;`), since TypeScript doesn't allow duplicate definitions.

This doesn't make sense to me, why does TypeScript use object property assignments as object keys and variable assignments as function arguments?

Wouldn't it make more sense to compile the `enum` to this:

```
var Fruit = Fruit || {};
Fruit.APPLE = Fruit[0] = "APPLE";
Fruit.ORANGE = Fruit[1] = "ORANGE";
```

Or this:

```
var Fruit = {};
Fruit.APPLE = Fruit[0] = "APPLE";
Fruit.ORANGE = Fruit[1] = "ORANGE";
```

Instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation of an assignation is the value. The purpose of the IIFE function is to create an object that works both ways **value -> key** and **key -> value**.

An interesting `console.log` here is `Fruit` itself.

---

```js
var Fruit;

(function (Fruit) {
    Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 50] = "APPLE";
    Fruit[Fruit["ORANGE"] = 10] = "ORANGE";
})(Fruit || (Fruit = {}));

// main.js
var bowl = [Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.ORANGE];
console.log(Fruit);
```

---

---

If we start over the whole explanation :

Fruit is passed to the IIFE function, if it doesn't exist, it's initialized as an empty object `{}`.

Then the first couple **key -> value** is inserted into the object, that will result as :

```
{
  APPLE: 50,
}
```

(Because the assignation is executed first on the line) :

```
Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 50] = "APPLE";
```

Then the second couple is inserted into `Fruit` object :

```
Fruit[50] = "APPLE";
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression `Fruit["APPLE"] = 0` evaluates to `0`, or the value of the key assignment. Which means that in addition to assigning

```
Fruit["APPLE"] = 0
```

we are also doing this assignment

```
Fruit[0] = "APPLE"
```

which makes it so that you can both get the string name of the enum by its number value and the number value by its string name.

Answer (score 2):

`Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 0]` doesn't mean to be `Fruit.APPLE`:

`Fruit["APPLE"] = 0` So, it is `Fruit[0]`. Now, `Fruit[0] = "APPLE"`.

Thus, you'll have:

```
Fruit[0] = "APPLE"
Fruit[1] = "ORANGE"
```

But not:

```
Fruit.APPLE = "APPLE"
Fruit.ORANGE = "ORANGE"
```

So, wrapping them inside IIFE:

```
(function (Fruit) {
  // here, Fruit is {}
})(Fruit || (Fruit = {}))
```

And when using:

```
Fruit[0] = "APPLE"
```

Will eventually become:

```
Fruit = { 0: "APPLE", 1: "ORANGE" }
```

Hence, your example will be invalid.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for taking the time and putting in the effort to answer this question.