# Javascript Object: assigning an index title back to an assignment operation for that index?

Tags: javascript

Recently came across the following bit of code in a TS/Angular tutorial:

```js
(function (Color) {
    Color[Color["Red"] = 0] = "Red";
    Color[Color["Green"] = 1] = "Green";
    Color[Color["Blue"] = 2] = "Blue";
})(Color || (Color = {}));
```

The only part I don't understand about the code is the nested lines - Color[Color["Red"] = 0] = "Red":  assignment of num values to string indices is happening with indexing of the object, and the string index is then assigned to it.

My questions are, what is "it" - i.e. what is "Red" being assigned to at the end of the line? Why is the assignment of the numeric value to the index occurring within indexing of the object?

Comment: You notice this is the *compilation output* of the TS code, right?

Comment: `"Red"` is assigned to `Color[0]` - the expression `Color["Red"] = 0` evaluates to `0`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021786/why-does-typescript-use-object-property-assignments-as-object-keys-and-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each assignment will return its value, so essentially `Color[Color["Green"] = 1] = "Green";` just means `Color["Green"] = 1 ; Color[1] = "Green";`

```js
Color = {}
console.log((Color["Red"] = 0))
console.log((Color["Green"] = 1))
console.log((Color["Blue"] = 2))
```